# Playing local/in-app mp4 files in a HTML5 videoplayer in a Cordova PhoneGap app on both Android 4.4 AND lower

Tags: video, cordova, android-webview, cordova-3

I got the video to work on Android 4.0.3 (API 15) and up using [Jaeger 25's Html5Video plugin](https://github.com/jaeger25/Html5Video). However, With the addition of Android 4.4 and its revised Chromium-based WebView, this plugin no longer suffices, [as mentioned by its awesome developer](https://github.com/jaeger25/Html5Video/issues/18#issuecomment-38365443).

Now, I would much rather play these video's without any plugins anyway (which works perfectly on iOS...), so I went back to trying that. Is was hoping that this Chromium-based webview would be friendlier with basic HTML5 playback, but instead, I just get the exact same error as before: `MediaPlayer(30579): Error (1,-2147483648)`.

I've spent hours trying several different approaches, all to no avail. I'll list a few things that I've tried below. Please, does anyone have any clues to point me in the right direction? I'm out of ideas...

**Normal file reference using *file:///***

Code:

```
    <video id="whoismad" width="75%" height="75%" loop class="videoplayer">
        <source src="file:///android_asset/www/res/raw/whoismad.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

Results in:

```
04-24 11:24:30.111: D/HTML5VideoViewProxy(30579): handleMessage - PLAY
04-24 11:24:30.119: D/HTML5VideoInline(30579): HTML5VideoInline created
04-24 11:24:30.127: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(30579): native_setup
04-24 11:24:30.127: V/MediaPlayer(30579): constructor
04-24 11:24:30.142: V/MediaPlayer(30579): setListener
04-24 11:24:30.189: V/MediaPlayer(30579): setVideoSurfaceTexture
04-24 11:24:30.189: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(30579): reset
04-24 11:24:30.189: V/MediaPlayer(30579): reset
04-24 11:24:30.236: V/MediaPlayer(30579): setVideoSurfaceTexture
04-24 11:24:30.236: V/MediaPlayer(30579): prepareAsync
04-24 11:24:30.244: V/MediaPlayer(30579): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-2147483648

04-24 11:24:30.244: E/MediaPlayer(30579): error (1, -2147483648)

04-24 11:24:30.244: V/MediaPlayer(30579): callback application
04-24 11:24:30.244: V/MediaPlayer(30579): back from callback

04-24 11:24:30.252: E/MediaPlayer(30579): Error (1,-2147483648)

04-24 11:24:30.267: D/HTML5VideoViewProxy(30579): handleMessage - ERROR
04-24 11:24:30.267: D/CordovaWebView(30579): Hidding Custom View
04-24 11:24:30.267: D/HTML5VideoViewProxy(30579): handleMessage - ENDED
04-24 11:24:30.283: D/HTML5VideoViewProxy(30579): handleMessage - SEEK
```

**File reference using Phonegap's Filesystem API**

Code:

```
    <video id="whoismad" width="75%" height="75%" loop class="videoplayer">
        <source src="cdvfile://android_asset/www/res/raw/whoismad.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

Results in (contains that same MediaPlayer (1, -2147483648) error):

```
04-24 11:30:56.705: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(30579): blockWebkitDraw
04-24 11:30:56.705: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(30579): blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse
04-24 11:30:57.033: D/webview(30579): blockWebkitViewMessage= false
04-24 11:30:57.056: D/HTML5VideoViewProxy(30579): handleMessage - PLAY
04-24 11:30:57.064: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(30579): reset
04-24 11:30:57.064: V/MediaPlayer(30579): reset
04-24 11:30:57.064: D/HTML5VideoInline(30579): HTML5VideoInline created
04-24 11:30:57.080: V/MediaPlayer(30579): setVideoSurfaceTexture
04-24 11:30:57.080: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(30579): reset
04-24 11:30:57.080: V/MediaPlayer(30579): reset
04-24 11:30:57.080: I/MediaPlayer(30579): path is null
04-24 11:30:57.095: D/MediaPlayer(30579): setDataSource IOException happend : 
04-24 11:30:57.095: D/MediaPlayer(30579): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: cdvfile://android_asset/www/res/raw/usm.mp4
04-24 11:30:57.095: D/MediaPlayer(30579):   at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:713)
04-24 11:30:57.095: D/MediaPlayer(30579):   at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:617)
04-24 11:30:57.095: D/MediaPlayer(30579):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:962)
04-24 11:30:57.095: D/MediaPlayer(30579):   at android.webkit.HTML5VideoView.prepareDataCommon(HTML5VideoView.java:326)
04-24 11:30:57.095: D/MediaPlayer(30579):   at android.webkit.HTML5VideoView.prepareDataAndDisplayMode(HTML5VideoView.java:363)
04-24 11:30:57.095: D/MediaPlayer(30579):   at android.webkit.HTML5VideoInline.prepareDataAndDisplayMode(HTML5VideoInline.java:72)
04-24 11:30:57.095: D/MediaPlayer(30579):   at android.webkit.HTML5VideoViewProxy$VideoPlayer.play(HTML5VideoViewProxy.java:286)
04-24 11:30:57.095: D/MediaPlayer(30579):   at android.webkit.HTML5VideoViewProxy.handleMessage(HTML5VideoViewProxy.java:462)
04-24 11:30:57.095: D/MediaPlayer(30579):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 11:30:57.095: D/MediaPlayer(30579):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
04-24 11:30:57.095: D/MediaPlayer(30579):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
04-24 11:30:57.095: D/MediaPlayer(30579):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 11:30:57.095: D/MediaPlayer(30579):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-24 11:30:57.095: D/MediaPlayer(30579):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
04-24 11:30:57.095: D/MediaPlayer(30579):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
04-24 11:30:57.095: D/MediaPlayer(30579):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 11:30:57.095: D/MediaPlayer(30579): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
04-24 11:30:57.095: V/MediaPlayer(30579): setVideoSurfaceTexture
04-24 11:30:57.103: V/MediaPlayer(30579): prepareAsync
04-24 11:30:57.103: V/MediaPlayer(30579): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-2147483648

04-24 11:30:57.103: E/MediaPlayer(30579): error (1, -2147483648)

04-24 11:30:57.103: V/MediaPlayer(30579): callback application
04-24 11:30:57.103: V/MediaPlayer(30579): back from callback

04-24 11:30:57.111: E/MediaPlayer(30579): Error (1,-2147483648)

04-24 11:30:57.142: D/HTML5VideoViewProxy(30579): handleMessage - ERROR
04-24 11:30:57.142: D/CordovaWebView(30579): Hidding Custom View
04-24 11:30:57.142: D/HTML5VideoViewProxy(30579): handleMessage - ENDED
04-24 11:30:57.158: D/HTML5VideoViewProxy(30579): handleMessage - SEEK
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this is not currently possible with Cordova 3.4 when attempting to read a video file out of the application assets.

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6079

It is possible to read the file if its copied to a directory outside the application assets, or the file is stored remotely.  But not in the app assets folder any longer.

I have a similar issue - my application has a welcome screen with a short video explaining the application (~300k) which I cannot play out of the APK itself.

Comment: Thanks so much for ruling this out. The link was already faded out so apparently I'd already seen this one, but just went past it... I simply couldn't believe that something so (seemingly) trivial could not be done. Summary: 

"An APK is like a JAR file, it's a special type of ZIP file that has the application's classes in it, as well as its resources and assets. For any file to be accessed from the assets, it must be decompressed. This is trivial for files that aren't video, but apparently due to the nature of video files, Android isn't able to decompress these files and play them."